# Copyright text as table on first page of an article in memoir class

Tags: memoir

I try to make a copyright text and suggested citation as table, appearing only on the first page of an article, breaking the abstract to the next page if necessary. So far, I had no great success.
I tried to manipulate the footer on the first page, but this is not a very solid solution. I want to keep it as simple as possible, since I want to combine various articles into a annual edition of a journal (using the `combine` class, probably).

Here is a code example:

```
% *****************************Document Class***************************************
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,article]{memoir}
% **********************************************************************************
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\setquotestyle{ngerman}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum} % This package generates blind text. It's not part of the example per se...


\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000
\displaywidowpenalty=10000


% *******************Page Style: Page Margins*************************************


\usepackage[inner=3.5cm,outer=3cm]{geometry}

%********************************************************************************

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
% ********************************************************************************

% ****************************Abstract Keywords***********************************
\def\keywordsG#1{{\textbf{Schlagworte}:} \textit{{#1}}} %
\def\keywordsEN#1{{\textbf{Keywords}:} \textit{{#1}}} %
% ********************************************************************************



\makeoddhead{plain}{\textit{Journal of all Journals (9) 2014} }{}{}
\makeevenhead{plain}{}{}{\theauthor}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{\\ \thepage}{}{} 
\makeevenfoot{plain}{}{}{\\ \thepage} 
\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{3\onelineskip}
%\setheaderspaces{*}{1.5\onelineskip}{*}

\copypagestyle{firstpage}{plain}
\makeoddhead{firstpage}{\textit{Journal of all Journals (9) 2014} }{}{}
\makeevenhead{firstpage}{}{}{\theauthor}
\makeoddfoot{firstpage}{



\begin{tabular}{r p{10cm}}
  \hline \\
  creative commons & This work is published under a Creative-Commons-License (Attribution-Share Alike 4.0). More information at  \url{http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/}.\\
\hline \\
Published by: & Journal of all Journals, 
ISSN 1111-2222 / 

URL: \url{http://journalofalljournals.net}, 
URN: urn:nbn:de:000-11111111-2\\
&\\
Suggested citation: & A. Author. 2014. \enquote{Title. Subtitle}. \textit{Journal of all Journals} 9(1), pp-pp. \\
\hline \\
\end{tabular}
\begin{center}
\thepage
\end{center}
}{}{} 
\makeevenfoot{firstpage}{}{\thepage}{}
\aliaspagestyle{title}{firstpage}

\setlength{\textheight}{450pt}



% ******************************Title & Author Info*********************************
\author{A. Author}
\date{}
\title{A Wonderful Title}
% *********************************************************************************



\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
% ********************German Abstract & Keywords***********************************
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\abstractrunin
\abslabeldelim{:}
\begin{abstract}
Vivamus eu tellus sed tellus consequat suscipit. Nam orci orci, malesuada id, gravida nec, ultricies vitae, erat. Donec risus turpis, luctus sit amet, interdum quis, porta sed, ipsum. Suspendisse condimentum, tortor at egestas posuere, neque metus tempor orci, et tincidunt urna nunc a purus. Sed facilisis blandit tellus. Nunc risus sem, suscipit nec, eleifend quis, cursus quis, libero. Curabitur et dolor. Sed vitae sem. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Maecenas ante. Duis ullamcorper enim. Donec tristique enim eu leo. Nullam molestie elit eu dolor. Nullam bibendum, turpis vitae tristique gravida, quam sapien tempor lectus, quis pretium tellus purus ac quam. Nulla facilisi.
\\

\keywordsG{Schlagwort1, Schlagwort 2, Schlagwort 3, Schlagwort 4}
\end{abstract}

% **********************************************************************************
\setlength{\textheight}{634pt}
%*********************English Abstract & Keywords***********************************
\selectlanguage{english}
\abstractrunin
\abslabeldelim{:}
\begin{abstract}
Vivamus eu tellus sed tellus consequat suscipit. Nam orci orci, malesuada id, gravida nec, ultricies vitae, erat. Donec risus turpis, luctus sit amet, interdum quis, porta sed, ipsum. Suspendisse condimentum, tortor at egestas posuere, neque metus tempor orci, et tincidunt urna nunc a purus. Sed facilisis blandit tellus. Nunc risus sem, suscipit nec, eleifend quis, cursus quis, libero. Curabitur et dolor. Sed vitae sem. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Maecenas ante. Duis ullamcorper enim. Donec tristique enim eu leo. Nullam molestie elit eu dolor. Nullam bibendum, turpis vitae tristique gravida, quam sapien tempor lectus, quis pretium tellus purus ac quam. Nulla facilisi.
\\

\keywordsEN{keyword1, keyword 2, keyword 3, keyword 4}
\end{abstract}

% **********************************************************************************

\pagestyle{plain}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}

% ***************************TABLE OF CONTENT***************************************
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Content}
\tableofcontents*
% **********************************************************************************


\section{First section}
\lipsum
\section{Second Section}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

What I want it to look like (as it looks right now, but the way is the problem) is that the copyright text and stuff should appear on the first page, right above the page number, below the main text, and this table should force the main text to break to the next page, if necessary.
Is there a better way? There must be, I bet. This seems very clumsy to me...

what I forgot to mention: the problem is not that the abstract's text does not continue on the next page, but that when it does, it causes the second page to keep the same layout (i.e. the same `\textheight`) like the first, although it should be the normal layout like page 3f.

*edit*
So far, it seems to me, the cleanest solution would be to define a new command to place a `figure` at the bottom of each page that I want it to appear. This keeps defining headings and footers minimal.
Here is, what I've done to accomplish this:

```
% *****************************Document Class***************************************
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,openany]{memoir}
% **********************************************************************************
% ******************************Titel & Autor Info*********************************
\author{}
\date{Vol. 9 * 2014}
\title{Journal of all Journals}
% *********************************************************************************

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\setquotestyle{ngerman}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum} % This package generates blind text. It's not part of the example per se...

% *******************Page Style: Page Margins*************************************
\usepackage[inner=4cm,outer=3cm]{geometry}

% ******************************Chapter Style*************************************
\chapterstyle{dash}

% *******************Überschriften Nummerierung***********************************
%Nummerierung der Überschriften aus \setsecnumdepth{none} oder an bis Ebene # \setcounter{secnumdepth}{#}

%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\setsecnumdepth{none}
% ********************************************************************************

% ****************************Abstract Keywords***********************************
\def\keywordsG#1{{\textbf{Schlagworte}:} \textit{{#1}}} %
\def\keywordsEN#1{{\textbf{Keywords}:} \textit{{#1}}} %
% ********************************************************************************

%***********************Header & Footer Article Normal Pages************************
\nouppercaseheads
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\makeoddhead{myheadings}{\textit{Journal of all Journals (9) 2014, S. ??--??} }{}{}
\makeevenhead{myheadings}{}{}{\thechapter}
\makeoddfoot{myheadings}{\\ \thepage}{}{} 
\makeevenfoot{myheadings}{}{}{\\ \thepage} 
\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{3\onelineskip}
%\setheaderspaces{*}{1.5\onelineskip}{*}
\aliaspagestyle{plain}{myheadings}

%***************Copyright & Citation********************************
\usepackage{array}
    \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}   


\newcommand{\CCC}[1]{%
\begin{figure}[b]
\begin{tabular}[b]{R{7.5em} L{10.2cm}}
    \hline \\
    creative commons & Dieses Werk wird unter den Bedingungen einer Creative-Commons-Lizenz (Attribution-Share Alike 4.0) veröffentlicht. Weitere Informationen unter  \protect\url{http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/}.\\
    \hline \\
    Ver{\"o}ffentlicht von: & Journal of All Journals, 


    ISSN 1111-2222 / URL: \url{http://joaj.net},

URN: \href{http://nbn-resolving.de/urn:nbn:de:0267-18625886-9}{urn:nbn:de:0267-18625886-9}\\
&\\
Recommended citation: & {#1} \\
& \\
\hline \\

\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
}
%**********************************************************************************
% *********************************************************************************
\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\cleardoublepage

% *********************************************************************************
% *********************************************************************************
\chapter[Erster Artikel (A. Autor)]{Erster Artikel}
% *****************Deutsche Zusammenfassung & Schlagworte**************************
\selectlanguage{ngerman}

\begin{center}
\textit{von A. Autor}
\break
\end{center}
\CCC{B. Autor. 2014. \enquote{Title}. \textit{Journal of all Journals}. 9(1): pp-pp.}
\abstractrunin
\abslabeldelim{:}
\begin{abstract}
Vivamus eu tellus sed tellus consequat suscipit. Nam orci orci, malesuada id, gravida nec, ultricies vitae, erat. Donec risus turpis, luctus sit amet, interdum quis, porta sed, ipsum. Suspendisse condimentum, tortor at egestas posuere, neque metus tempor orci, et tincidunt urna nunc a purus. Sed facilisis blandit tellus. Nunc risus sem, suscipit nec, eleifend quis, cursus quis, libero. Curabitur et dolor. Sed vitae sem. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Maecenas ante. Duis ullamcorper enim. Donec tristique enim eu leo. Nullam molestie elit eu dolor. Nullam bibendum, turpis vitae tristique gravida, quam sapien tempor lectus, quis pretium tellus purus ac quam. Nulla facilisi.Vivamus eu tellus sed tellus consequat suscipit. Nam orci orci, malesuada id, gravida nec, ultricies vitae, erat. Donec risus turpis, luctus sit amet, interdum quis, porta sed, ipsum. Suspendisse condimentum, tortor at egestas posuere, neque metus tempor orci, et tincidunt urna nunc a purus. Sed facilisis blandit tellus. Nunc risus sem, suscipit nec, eleifend quis, cursus quis, libero. Curabitur et dolor. Sed vitae sem. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Maecenas ante. Duis ullamcorper enim. Donec tristique enim eu leo. Nullam molestie elit eu dolor. Nullam bibendum, turpis vitae tristique gravida, quam sapien tempor lectus, quis pretium tellus purus ac quam. Nulla facilisi.
\\

\keywordsG{Schlagwort1, Schlagwort2, Schlagwort3, Schlagwort4}
\end{abstract}

% **********************************************************************************

\lipsum
\cleardoublepage

% **********************************************************************************
% **********************************************************************************

\chapter[Zweiter Artikel (B. Autor)]{Zweiter Artikel}
\CCC{A. Autor. 2014. \enquote{Title}. \textit{Journal of all Journals} (9), pp-pp.}
\begin{center}
\emph{von B. Autor}
\end{center}

\lipsum
% **********************************************************************************
% **********************************************************************************

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this still leaves the issue with the `\thechapter` mark (I think it is not related, or is it? I asked the question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215530/thechapter-displays-only-0-in-header-in-memoir-class) ) unsolved, but seems to be a clean and easy way.

The advantage is, that I don't have to combine articles with the `combine`class, but can easily collect articles as chapters in a book. Using headers and footers and single documents, combined afterwards, would be a total mess, considering all the definitions I had to make for headers and footers of each document. It all, however, doesn't solve the original problem (thanks to [@daleif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3929/daleif) for the reminder).

Comment: Regarding the edit. You should consider making a better interface for the start of each article (which I assume will be the chapters). Then basically you have free range as to how you format the title page of each article. I tend to provide a special environment inside which the data for the article has to be specified. If you are clever you use environ to collect, say the contents of the abstract and then you can move it around as much you like before typesetting it. You can even use that `\enlargethispage` trick I used.

Comment: Your second example is the way that I have done it in the past. Just use a bottom captionless figure or table.

Comment: @PeterWilson, looking at it again, I agree it is simplest to use `\begin{table}[!b]`. Even better to provide a special start of article interface where all the title, author etc is registered. Macros can then build the copyright notice and add it. This approach will also work for chapter title pages.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing there are better ways, which I'd also like to hear about.

Here is one way (I've removed a lot to make the example simpler)

```
% *****************************Document Class***************************************
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,article]{memoir}
% **********************************************************************************
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\setquotestyle{ngerman}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\usepackage{lipsum} 
%\usepackage[inner=3.5cm,outer=3cm]{geometry}
\setlrmarginsandblock{3.5cm}{3cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout


%********************************************************************************

%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}

\setsecnumdepth{none}


\usepackage{picture,calc}
\newsavebox\CopyRight
\newlength\makeway

\AtBeginDocument{
\begin{lrbox}{\CopyRight}
  \normalfont\normalsize
  \begin{tabular}[b]{r p{10cm}}
    \hline \\
    creative commons & This work is published under a Creative-Commons-License (Attribution-Share Alike 4.0). More information at  \protect\url{http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/}.\\
    \hline \\
    Published by: & Journal of all Journals, 
    ISSN 1111-2222 / 

URL: \url{http://journalofalljournals.net}, 
URN: urn:nbn:de:000-11111111-2\\
&\\
Suggested citation: & A. Author. 2014. {Title. Subtitle}. \textit{Journal of all Journals} 9(1), pp-pp. \\
\hline \\
\end{tabular}
\end{lrbox}
\setlength\makeway{\dimexpr\ht\CopyRight+\dp\CopyRight-0.5em}
\enlargethispage{-\makeway}
}

\setlength\parskip{0pt}


\copypagestyle{firstpage}{plain}
\makeoddhead{firstpage}{\textit{Journal of all Journals (9) 2014} }{}{}
\makeevenhead{firstpage}{}{}{\theauthor}
\makeoddfoot{firstpage}{%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(0,\footskip-0.5em){\usebox{\CopyRight}}
  \end{picture}
}{\thepage}{} 
\makeevenfoot{firstpage}{}{\thepage}{}
\aliaspagestyle{title}{firstpage}



\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{title}

\lipsum


\end{document}
```

Comment: great! this does solve it. In hope for another, maybe simpler answer, I don't mark it as solved yet, if that's OK (I think, it might be in your interest too).

Comment: Exactly. It is an interesting problem, and there ought to be a *good* solution to the problem: leave x number of lines blank at the bottom of this particular page

Comment: Is there any way to do this also for chapters? The solution you provided uses the `\AtBeginDocument` hook... would be great, if one could do the same for chapters.

The reason I ask is, because then I could write a layout for chapters, which mimes the title, do the trick above for chapters, and easily combine all articles for an annual collection with its own toc, introduction, etc.

Comment: You could just hook into the chapters, there is the `\memendofchapterhook` which does nothing by default. I do not remember if that hook is actually documented.

Comment: this kind of solves the issue, but then every first page of a chapter breaks after a couple of lines, even if it should not contain the defined footer. Could I turn the definition after `\memendofchapterhook`on and off for different chapters? I also modified my question - maybe a cleaner solution would be to place a textblock or minipage or something like this at the bottom of every first page of a chapter...

Comment: Then update your question with this new MWE (and please make it minimal). BTW: have a look at the docmute package, might be more interesting than `combine`