# \thechapter displays only 0 in header in memoir class

Tags: header-footer, memoir

another issue I came across and can't find any solution is that, defining a new page style in memoir class, `\thechapter` mark does not display anything but a lovely 0 in the header. If I replace `\thechapter` with `\thepage` or `\theautor` - both work, only `\thechapter` doesn't.

Here is the code: what did I miss?

```
% *****************************Document Class***************************************
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,openany]{memoir}
% **********************************************************************************
% ******************************Titel & Autor Info*********************************
\author{}
\date{Vol. 9 * 2014}
\title{Journal of all Journals}
% *********************************************************************************


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\setquotestyle{ngerman}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum} % This package generates blind text. It's not part of the example per se...



% *******************Page Style: Page Margins*************************************


\usepackage[inner=4cm,outer=3cm]{geometry}


% ******************************Chapter Style*************************************
\chapterstyle{dash}

% *******************Überschriften Nummerierung***********************************
%Nummerierung der Überschriften aus \setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1} oder an bis Ebene # \setcounter{secnumdepth}{#}

%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\setsecnumdepth{none}
% ********************************************************************************

% ****************************Abstract Keywords***********************************
\def\keywordsG#1{{\textbf{Schlagworte}:} \textit{{#1}}} %
\def\keywordsEN#1{{\textbf{Keywords}:} \textit{{#1}}} %
% ********************************************************************************

%***********************Header & Footer Article Normal Pages************************
\nouppercaseheads
\copypagestyle{myheadings}{plain}
\makeoddhead{myheadings}{\textit{Journal of all Journals (9) 2014, S. ??--??} }{}{}
\makeevenhead{myheadings}{}{}{\thechapter}
\makeoddfoot{myheadings}{\\ \thepage}{}{} 
\makeevenfoot{myheadings}{}{}{\\ \thepage} 
\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{3\onelineskip}
%\setheaderspaces{*}{1.5\onelineskip}{*}
\aliaspagestyle{plain}{myheadings}


%***********************Header & Footer Article First Page************************
\usepackage{picture,calc}
\newsavebox\CopyRight
\newlength\makeway

\renewcommand\memendofchapterhook{%

\begin{lrbox}{\CopyRight}
  \normalfont\normalsize
  \begin{tabular}[b]{r p{10cm}}
    \hline \\
    creative commons & This work is published under a Creative-Commons-License (Attribution-Share Alike 4.0). More information at  \protect\url{http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/}.\\
    \hline \\
    Published by: & Journal of all Journals, 
    ISSN 1111-2222 / 

URL: \url{http://journalofalljournals.net}, 
URN: urn:nbn:de:000-11111111-2\\
&\\
Suggested citation: & A. Author. 2014. {Title. Subtitle}. \textit{Journal of all Journals} 9(1), pp-pp. \\
\hline \\
\end{tabular}
\end{lrbox}
\setlength\makeway{\dimexpr\ht\CopyRight+\dp\CopyRight-0.5em}
\enlargethispage{-\makeway}
}

\setlength\parskip{0pt}



\copypagestyle{firstpage}{plain}
\makeoddhead{firstpage}{\textit{Journal of all Journals (9) 2014, S. ??--??} }{}{}
\makeevenhead{firstpage}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{firstpage}{%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(0,\footskip-0.5em){\usebox{\CopyRight}}
  \end{picture}
}{\thepage}{} 
\makeevenfoot{firstpage}{%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(0,\footskip-0.5em){\usebox{\CopyRight}}
  \end{picture}
}{\thepage}{}



\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\selectlanguage{ngerman}

\begin{titlingpage}
\maketitle
\end{titlingpage}
\section{Impressum}
\tableofcontents* 

\thispagestyle{empty}


\chapter{Vorwort der Herausgeberinnen}

\mainmatter
\pagestyle{plain}
\cleardoublepage
\chapter[Erster Artikel (A. Autor)]{Erster Artikel}

\thispagestyle{firstpage}
% *****************Deutsche Zusammenfassung & Schlagworte**************************
\selectlanguage{ngerman}

\begin{center}
\textit{von A. Autor}
\break
\end{center}

\abstractrunin
\abslabeldelim{:}
\begin{abstract}
Vivamus eu tellus sed tellus consequat suscipit. Nam orci orci, malesuada id, gravida nec, ultricies vitae, erat. Donec risus turpis, luctus sit amet, interdum quis, porta sed, ipsum. Suspendisse condimentum, tortor at egestas posuere, neque metus tempor orci, et tincidunt urna nunc a purus. Sed facilisis blandit tellus. Nunc risus sem, suscipit nec, eleifend quis, cursus quis, libero. Curabitur et dolor. Sed vitae sem. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Maecenas ante. Duis ullamcorper enim. Donec tristique enim eu leo. Nullam molestie elit eu dolor. Nullam bibendum, turpis vitae tristique gravida, quam sapien tempor lectus, quis pretium tellus purus ac quam. Nulla facilisi.Vivamus eu tellus sed tellus consequat suscipit. Nam orci orci, malesuada id, gravida nec, ultricies vitae, erat. Donec risus turpis, luctus sit amet, interdum quis, porta sed, ipsum. Suspendisse condimentum, tortor at egestas posuere, neque metus tempor orci, et tincidunt urna nunc a purus. Sed facilisis blandit tellus. Nunc risus sem, suscipit nec, eleifend quis, cursus quis, libero. Curabitur et dolor. Sed vitae sem. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Maecenas ante. Duis ullamcorper enim. Donec tristique enim eu leo. Nullam molestie elit eu dolor. Nullam bibendum, turpis vitae tristique gravida, quam sapien tempor lectus, quis pretium tellus purus ac quam. Nulla facilisi.
\\

\keywordsG{Schlagwort1, Schlagwort2, Schlagwort3, Schlagwort4}
\end{abstract}

% **********************************************************************************

%*********************English Abstract & Keywords***********************************
\selectlanguage{english}
\abstractrunin
\abslabeldelim{:}
\begin{abstract}
Vivamus eu tellus sed tellus consequat suscipit. Nam orci orci, malesuada id, gravida nec, ultricies vitae, erat. Donec risus turpis, luctus sit amet, interdum quis, porta sed, ipsum. Suspendisse condimentum, tortor at egestas posuere, neque metus tempor orci, et tincidunt urna nunc a purus. Sed facilisis blandit tellus. Nunc risus sem, suscipit nec, eleifend quis, cursus quis, libero. Curabitur et dolor. Sed vitae sem. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Maecenas ante. Duis ullamcorper enim. Donec tristique enim eu leo. Nullam molestie elit eu dolor. Nullam bibendum, turpis vitae tristique gravida, quam sapien tempor lectus, quis pretium tellus purus ac quam. Nulla facilisi.
\\

\keywordsEN{keyword1, keyword 2, keyword 3, keyword 4}
\end{abstract}

% **********************************************************************************
\selectlanguage{ngerman}

% **********************************************************************************


\lipsum
\lipsum
\cleardoublepage
\chapter[Zweiter Artikel (B. Autor)]{Zweiter Artikel}

\thispagestyle{firstpage}
\begin{center}
\emph{von B. Autor}
\end{center}

\lipsum


\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use `\thechapter`, use `\leftmark` and `\rightmark` and customize them via `\markboth`. See `memman.pdf` (`memoir` official manual) for further details.

Comment: As @Astrinus mentioned, use `\leftmark`. `thechapter` is printing the number of the chapter. In your case, it is zero for the frontmatter, and (still) zero for the mainmatter as you used `setsecnumdepth` to `none`.

Comment: IIRC, page is the only counter originally set to one.  All others start off at zero.

Comment: @Astrinus Can you make an answer from your comment?

Comment: @Astrinus An answer would be nice. I would even give you an upvote ;-)

Answer (score 1):

From the comment of Astrinus:

Don't use `\thechapter`, use `\leftmark` and `\rightmark` and customize them via `\markboth`. See `memman.pdf` (memoir official manual, via `texdoc memman`) for further details.